# Angular-Kendo grid edit template - how to get access to those fields in the controller code

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

In my AngularJS app, I'm using a Kendo grid with an edit template. This way when a user clicks on the EDIT button, I can control the editable fields in the modal popup.

Now in this edit template, I have added some custom functionality; that is, a simple "Add" option. This Add option will call into a function within my controller code. All good so far.

The problem is: when I click on the "Add" link, I cannot get access to the fields within the controller by way of `dataItem.fieldName` .

Here's my HTML :

```
   <div class="col-lg-5">  
            <span id="userKriGrid"
                kendo-grid="settings.userRiskMsrGrid" 
                k-data-source="settings.userRiskMsrGridDS"
                k-options="settings.riskMsrGridOptions" 
                k-rebind="settings.riskMsrGridOptions">
            </span>
   </div>
```

and the grid settings within my js controller:

```js
settings.riskMsrGridOptions = {   // Kendo grid settings
 selectable: true,
 columns: [
   { field: "id", width: "10px", hidden: true },
   { field: "name", title: "Risk Measure", width: "5px", },                           
   { field: "kri_group", title: "Cube", width: "20px", hidden: true },
   { field: "kri", title: "Result Vector", width: "20px", hidden: true},
   { field: "kri_alias", title: "KRI Name", width: "20px", hidden:true },
   { field: "aggreg_formula", title: "KRI Expression", width: "35px", hidden: true },
   { command: [{ name: "edit", text: '' }, { name: "destroy", text: '' }], title: "Edit", width: "5px" }
 ],
 editable: {
  mode: "popup",
  template: kendo.template($("#editorTemplate").html())   // loaded up in index.html  
 },
 edit: function (e) {
  var window = e.container.data("kendoWindow");
  window.title("Risk Measure Edit");
 }            
};
```

And I'm loading an external template (i.e. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/load-remote ).
Please note the `ng-click` event in the button calls into `settings.addToDefRiskMsr(e)`

```html
<script id="editorTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
 <form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>    
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Risk Measure</label>  
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="textinput" ng-model="dataItem.name"  class="form-control input-md" type="text" >            
   </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">  <!-- ADD BUTTON HERE !!! -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="settings.addToDefRiskMsr(e)" >
                  <span title="add to Risk Measure grid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add to DRM
                </button>                
            </div>
  </div>

 

  </fieldset>
 </form>
</script>
```

Again, the template code above uses `dataItem.fieldName` to pull the field I want to the user have edit access to.

Now how do I get access to that field within my controller ? `dataItem.name` DOES NOT WORK !

```
    settings.addToDefRiskMsr = function (e) {
        var riskMeasureName = dataItem.name;    // NOT WORKING !!!
```

your advice is appreciated.

regards,
Bob
       }

Comment: Hey have you tried seeing if `$scope.dataItem.name` is the item you are trying to get?

Comment: I need to review my code. I may have resolved it, and forgot to update here.

Comment: cool let me know i'd be happy to look into this with you. Do you have a Pluker for this?

Comment: Hi @bob.mazzo, how did you resolve this? I've just ran into the same issue. In fact, I'm not using scope, I use the latest "controllerAs" method, which means I access all the fields in my template as `ctrl.dataItem.myfield`. But when I try to use the same inside my controller, there's no `dataItem` at all!

Comment: oh my goodness. I'm sorry for never having posted my final resolution on this. I will have to check the code at home tonight...I'll get back to you on this...

Comment: Never mind, I found  the solution, I will post is as answer for those who still arrive to this page today :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the original jQuery-based Kendo UI (i.e. not the new version made from the ground-up for Angular 2) with Angular 1.5+ and you're using the `controllerAs` method, you may find that the `dataItem` field is not always accessible in your controller. In my case, I had an edit template with an `ng-show` attribute which was calling a controller method, passing a `dataItem` field, and I noticed that `dataItem` was sometimes undefined inside the controller. So, my solution was to inject `$scope` in the controller and then `dataItem` is accessible as `$scope.$parent.dataItem`.

Imho, this is a bug in Kendo UI.